# How to say, "Let's test your sense of direction. How do we get to the car from here?"

Tags: mandarin

Would the following be the appropriate translation for "Let's test your sense of direction. How do we get to the car from here?"

It feels awkward, like English grammar forced into Chinese grammar. :)

我考妳的方向的。離這裡走我車怎麼樣？

Comment: Google translate: 讓我測試你的方向感 - 我們如何從這裡走到汽車

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“**Let's**(Google: 让我们) = "**让我**" but you can use "来"

**test** = 考, but it is better to use reduplication "**考考**"

**your** = **妳的** (it is easy)

**sense of direction**. = **方向感** (it is a common term )

**吧** (optional final particle)

> [How do we] [get to the car] [from here?]

Google translates "**get to** the car" as "**到达**汽车", but the native way is "**走到**汽车**那边**"

> [我们如何] [到达汽车] [**从这里**？]

English place the location "from **here**" after the verb clause "get to the car" but Chinese would put the location before it, so the correct order is

> [我们如何] [**从这里**] [走到汽车那边?]

“Let's test your sense of direction. How do we get to the car from here?”

**Translation**:

"让我考考妳的方向感吧, 我们如何从这里走到汽车那边?"

Comment: could you say 離這裡 instead of 从这里? also would it be grammatically wrong to omit 那邊？

Comment: also instead of 如何, could you say 怎麼樣？ 怎麼樣 feels more casual than 如何, is that a fair statement to make? thanks again!

Comment: 从这里 means "from here" ; 離這裡 means "distance from here",  so, 从这里 or 由这里 is the correct one; you can use 如何 or 怎麼樣/ 怎樣. "如何" is more literary and 怎樣 is more colloquial

Comment: 謝謝你的clarification！感謝！

Comment: also would it be grammatically wrong to omit 那邊？

Comment: Since 汽车 is not a location, 那邊/ 那里/ (any words that indicate a location') cannot be omitted. If the sentence was " How do we get to the parking lot" then you don't need 那邊 or 那里,  just write: "我们怎樣从这里走到停车场?"

Comment: thanks again! interesting. you're saying in mandarin, "汽車“ cannot represent the car's location whereas it could in english (i.e., you don't need to say, "How do we get to the car's location from here?"). is this true for cantonese as well? thanks so much!

Comment: "the car's location" is "汽車的(所在地)" or  "汽車(的位置)" ; "How do we get to the car's location from here?" can be translated as " 我们怎樣从这里走到汽車(的所在地)?" or " 我们怎樣从这里走到汽車(的位置)?" , " ~ 的所在地" is more literary ; "~ 的位置" is more colloquial

Comment: >is this true for cantonese as well? Yes, it is the same in Cantonese

Answer (score 1):

Let's test your sense of direction.
让我们来测试一下你的方向感。
How do we get to the car from here?
从这里怎么找到我们停车的地方？
从这里怎么去我们停车的地方？
我们把车停在哪儿？

Apparently, it grates on Chinese ears to say 'get to the car,' because 'car' is not a position, 'get to where we parked the car' is better.